# Tomcat/Apache Solr in Amazon S3? Is that possible?

Tags: tomcat, solr, amazon-web-services

How may I install (if it can be done) Apache Solr with Tomcat on Amazon S3 service? Is that possible?

I´ve got a Drupal site and would like to use Apache solr in my site, without the overload (and without paying to services like Acquia, that sadly are far too expensive for my budget).

If not S3, which Amazon service could do the job?

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to run Solr with Tomcat on S3, you'd have to create an Amazon EC2 instance to do that. You can launch a ubuntu instance from your AWS console and then look for a decent tutorial, something like: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way

Comment: In addition amazon has elastic search which may be another option.

Comment: ElasticSearch is not an Amazon product. Its also a REST on Lucene.

Comment: If you're looking for search, you can try Amazon CloudSearch, which is internal AWS service based on solr.